# Import data from several file in a loop with numpy getfromtxt

Tags: python, string, numpy, csv

I have several files named for years like 'mcps2007.csv'. I need to run an analysis over all the data set year for year, and store new data e plots. There is a clever way to import from file and export to new files changing only the year in the code?

Each variable has been stored in a file, like all the quantities and graphs of interest.

```
np.savetxt("p2008.csv", p, delimiter=",")
```

In a first moment I run the analysis year for year changing the input and output year for all files (15 files circa) and re-running the program over the new data set each time (the program take one hour for analysis), but it is long and boring and I need to stay close to the pc every moment to re-run the program.

In a second moment I copied the code (like I did in the following example), and changing manually every variable and every file I can now run the program in one shot, but the code is a mess and the process of copying and changing is long, boring and full of debugging issues.

Example of code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
import statsmodels.stats.multitest as multi


p07 = genfromtxt('p2007.csv', delimiter=',')
p08 = genfromtxt('p2008.csv', delimiter=',')
p09 = genfromtxt('p2009.csv', delimiter=',')
p10 = genfromtxt('p2010.csv', delimiter=',')
p11 = genfromtxt('p2011.csv', delimiter=',')
p12 = genfromtxt('p2012.csv', delimiter=',')
p13 = genfromtxt('p2013.csv', delimiter=',')
p14 = genfromtxt('p2014.csv', delimiter=',')
p15 = genfromtxt('p2015.csv', delimiter=',')
p16 = genfromtxt('p2016.csv', delimiter=',')

p07 = p07.flatten()
p08 = p08.flatten()
p09 = p09.flatten()
p10 = p10.flatten()
p11 = p11.flatten()
p12 = p12.flatten()
p13 = p13.flatten()
p14 = p14.flatten()
p15 = p15.flatten()
p16 = p16.flatten()

q07 = multi.multipletests (p07, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
q08 = multi.multipletests (p08, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
q09 = multi.multipletests (p09, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
q10 = multi.multipletests (p10, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
q11 = multi.multipletests (p11, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
q12 = multi.multipletests (p12, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
q13 = multi.multipletests (p13, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
q14 = multi.multipletests (p14, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
q15 = multi.multipletests (p15, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
q16 = multi.multipletests (p16, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
```

Is there a clever way to change only one time in the code the year so that the input and output file's name will change accordingly, and moreover there is a way to loop the program over the 10 years I need to analyze without re-running the program every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [] # to store your p07..p16
res = [] # to store your q07..q16

for d in range(07,16+1):
    p = genfromtxt('p20' + str(d) + '.csv', delimiter=',')
    p.flatten()
    q = multi.multipletests (p, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
    # save objects
    data.append(p)
    res.append(q)
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is to make a function and then run it within a loop for the number of years you have. Like the following:

```
def your_function(file_name):
    data = genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',')
    data = data.flatten()
    dt = multi.multipletests(data, 1e-5, method='bonferroni')
    return dt

data = []
for file in files: # You need to define files first
    data.append(your_function(file))
```

Comment: If I'm understanding I have to  define files like the list of the files name. Moreover it is possible to define in python function of function? Something like `def your_function(file_name, another_function):` In this way I could use this way of iterating for almost every step of the analysis without defining a new function every time.

Comment: You can do that using the package glob (import glob).. define a path where you store the csv files.. And then write in the loop: for file in glob.glob(path+'*.csv'):